# Find how a is defined with each underscore representing a character

Tags: computer-puzzle

Here is a puzzle for python programmers (python3+):

Find how `a` is defined (for example, `a = 2 + True`), with each underscore representing a character (there is no trail of whitespaces on the left and right)

```
a = _____
print(a+a)
```

Output:

Edit for narrowing down the answer:

Here are the only characters you can work with:
 , `,`, `"`, `+`

Comment: You should specify the version of Python. For example, in python 2.*, `a = ur' '` would've worked. It doesn't in newer versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

> " """

Explanation:

> This is simply the concatenation of a single space " " and the empty string "". The three quotation marks on the right are not parsed as a triple quote because the first one is paired with the one before the space.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm reading the puzzle correctly, easiest answer would be

> a=' '*1

Explanation:

> The output is two spaces, and there are 5 underscores for the value of a. Output is achieved by concatenating a to a, so we know a must be a single space, achieved using 5 characters. In Python a string can be duplicated using multiply, so we have the string of a single space (3 characters), multiplied by 1 (an additional two characters).

Comment: There are lots of ways to burn the two excess characters: `" "##` `f" ";` `r' ';` `(' ')` or even `" ";\ ` I'm sure there are more.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yeah, there are a ton. I just figured my answer was the easiest to explain to a non-programmer while still looking "pythony" (I forget the term pythonistas use to describe python code)

Comment: I suspect OP had one very specific answer in mind and underestimated how many other ways there are, cf their edits.